# Javapackager - NoSuchFileException while copying libraries JDK 9

Tags: java, exception, java-9, javapackager

When I use the [javapacker command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719), I get a `NoSuchFileException` when it should copy the libraries to the app folder. I'm running the following command:

```
javapackager -deploy -nosign -v -native image -name test 
-appclass test.Test 
-srcdir "E:\projects\test\target"
-srcfiles test-1.0.jar;lib
-outdir "E:\projects\test\target\dist"
```

Anything seams to work fine, but i get the NoSuchFileException inside the output and the libraries inside the **lib** folder are missing (did not get copied).

```
Running [D:\Java64\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java.exe, -version]
Creating app bundle: test in E:\projects\test\target\dist
"Adding modules: [java.rmi, java.sql, javafx.web, ... long list ... 
outputDir = E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\runtime
modulePath = [D:\Java64\jdk-9.0.4\jmods]
addModules = [java.rmi, java.sql, javafx.web, ... long list ...
limitModules = []
excludeFileList = .*\.diz
stripNativeCommands = true
userArguments = {}
Using default package resource [icon]  (add package/windows/test.ico to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [Template for creating executable properties file.]  (add package/windows\test.properties to the class path to customize)
Running [D:\Java64\jdk-9.0.4\bin\javapackager.exe, --icon-swap, C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15945263774290817340\windows\test.ico, E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\test.exe]
Icon File Name: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15945263774290817340\windows\test.ico
Executable File Name: E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\test.exe
Running [D:\Java64\jdk-9.0.4\bin\javapackager.exe, --version-swap, C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15945263774290817340\windows\test.properties, E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\test.exe]
Resource File Name: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15945263774290817340\windows\test.properties
Executable File Name: E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\test.exe
Exception: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: E:\projects\test\target\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar -> E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\app\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
Config files are saved to C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15945263774290817340\windows. Use them to customize package.
Result application bundle: E:\projects\test\target\dist
```

I don't know what the following line of the output is trying to tell me. The file clearly exists inside my *lib* folder and the javapackager did find it itself by looking inside the *lib* folder, that I provided with the `-srcfiles test-1.0.jar;lib` argument.

```
Exception: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: E:\projects\test\target\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar -> E:\projects\test\target\dist\test\app\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
```

Any idea why javapacker complains that the file would not exist?

Answer (score -2):

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719, 
`-srcfiles` should be provided with a list of files. `lib` is a directory. I would try using `-srcdir`.

Also, if you get

> Exception: java.lang.Exception: Error: Modules are not allowed in srcfiles

it means you have to use `--module-path`, and then set the main module using `-m <module name>`